# Error at using hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.7.7.jar

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

I have hadoop

> hadoop@nodo1:/opt/hadoop$ hadoop version Hadoop 2.7.7 Subversion
>   Unknown -r c1aad84bd27cd79c3d1a7dd58202a8c3ee1ed3ac Compiled by stevel
>   on 2018-07-18T22:47Z Compiled with protoc 2.5.0 From source with
>   checksum 792e15d20b12c74bd6f19a1fb886490 This command was run using
>   /opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.7.7.jar

And as learned in a course, I use

```
/opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.7.7.jar wordcount
```

But when i run this, the next error is shown:

> hadoop@nodo1:/opt/hadoop$ hadoop jar
>   /opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.7.7.jar
>   wordcount /libros /output3
>
> org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileAlreadyExistsException: Output directory
>   hdfs://nodo1:9000/output3 already exists
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat.checkOutputSpecs(FileOutputFormat.java:146)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.checkSpecs(JobSubmitter.java:266)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:139)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1290)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1287)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1762)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1287)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1308)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.examples.WordCount.main(WordCount.java:87)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver$ProgramDescription.invoke(ProgramDriver.java:71)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver.run(ProgramDriver.java:144)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.examples.ExampleDriver.main(ExampleDriver.java:74)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:226)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:141)

In the path i have a book

> hadoop@nodo1:/opt/hadoop$ hdfs dfs -ls /libros/ Found 1 items
>   -rw-r--r--   1 hadoop supergroup    2198927 2018-11-02 10:22 /libros/quijote.txt

TNK from your help

Comment: Can you check whats inside output3

Answer (score 1):

First do

```
hdfs dfs -ls /output3
```

If there is a file then,

Either **Delete**, Output directory `hdfs://nodo1:9000/output3` or,

Use **different** file name

```
# Change output3 to output4
hadoop jar /opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.7.7.jar wordcount /libros /output4
```